# Como listar os arquivos de um diretório e subdiretórios que contém um texto específico, no Linux?

Tags: linux, arquivo

Como listar todos os arquivos de um diretório e subdiretórios que contém um texto específico e juntamente a linha correspondente em que aparece o texto, no Linux?

Comment: Por favor explique melhor o que quer fazer e o que já tentou fazer Qual o sistema operacional e maiores detalhes do problema e do ambiente. ALém da solução esperada.

Comment: Tente o ack: http://beyondgrep.com/

Comment: Alterei a pergunta para ser mais específica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma ferramenta para fazer isso é o comando `grep`.
A sintaxe é `grep -rin "expressao_procurada"`

Um exemplo de uso seria procura a definição de uma função chamada gerar_relatorio em vários arquivos fonte Python.

`grep -rin "^def *gerar_relatorio" *.py`

O `-rin` é para (r)ser recursivo, (i)ignorar o case e (n) colocar o numero da linha na saída do console.

Comment: O parâmetro `-l` também é muito útil, faz o `grep` imprimir somente a lista dos arquivos que contém o texto procurado, sem incluir a linha de texto em si. É um output mais limpo, e essa lista nesse formato é mais adequada para ser passada como input de outros programas.

Answer (score 3):

Eu fiz assim e funcionou: `grep -rl "algum-texto" /caminho-do-diretório`.

Onde:

- a opção `-r` serve para você informar que deseja procurar em todos os subdiretórios;
- a opção `-l` serve para você informar que deseja exibir apenas os nomes dos arquivos, ao invés das linhas de texto que casam com a sua busca

Espero ter ajudado ainda mais!

Answer (score 2):

```
find /diretorio -exec grep -Fi "texto_especifico" {} \;
```

O comando `find` "procura" recursivamente em "*diretorio*" todos os arquivos que contenham o "*texto_especifico*" buscado pelo `grep`.

Para listar os arquivos acrescente a opção `-l` no comando `grep`

```
find /diretorio -exec grep -Fil "texto_especifico" {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo,
você pode utilizar o comando GREP
EX: grep -ri "texto_da_busca" /diretorio .
Segue um link que explica melhor o funcionamento do grep:
http://blog.glauco.mp/filtragem-de-dados-com-o-comando-grep/

Comment: Boa resposta, mas quando usar links como referencia de resposta procure sempre colocar uma parte do conteúdo do link :)

Comment: Ok Silvio! valeu pela dica!

Answer (score 1):

```
ack  regExp  diretorio
ack  regExp
```